VSCode - prevent jumping annotations/inlay hints on edit
Is there a way to prevent jumping behavior of annotations in vscode?
Removing and adding smth. will make some grey annotations to appear/disappear which makes everything jump left and right (it's hard to edit quickly).

Filling the required amount of characters- >
Only use the visual-studio-code tag for questions about the features and functionality of the Visual Studio Code editor itself, not merely because you are using it to write the code you’re asking about.
